# Rank records on the basis of a field value in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping, ranking

I have a field `distribution` in record schema that looks likes this:

```
...
"distribution": {
    "properties": {
        "availability": {
            "type": "keyword"
         } 
     }
}
...
```

I want to rank the records with `distribution.availability == "ondemand"` lower than other records.

I looked in Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) but can't find a way to reduce the scores of this type of records in **index-time** to appear lower in search results.

How can I achieve this, any pointers to related source would be enough as well.

More Info:

I was completely omitting these `ondemand` records with help of python client in **query-time** like this:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Q

_query = Q("query_string", query=query_string) & ~Q('match', **{'availability.keyword': 'ondemand'})
```

Now, I want to include these records but I want to place them lower than other records.

If it is not possible to implement something like this in **index-time**, please suggest how can I achieve this in **query-time** with python client.

After applying the suggestion from llermaly, the python client query looks like this:

```
boosting_query = Q(
    "boosting",
    positive=Q("match_all"),
    negative=Q(
        "bool", filter=[Q({"term": {"distribution.availability.keyword": "ondemand"}})]
    ),
    negative_boost=0.5,
)
if query_string:
    _query = Q("query_string", query=query_string) & boosting_query
else:
    _query = Q() & boosting_query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2** : [elasticsearch-dsl-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) version of boosting query

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q

client = Elasticsearch()
q = Q('boosting', positive=Q("match_all"), negative=Q('bool', filter=[Q({"term": {"test.available.keyword": "ondemand"}})]), negative_boost=0.5)
s = Search(using=client, index="test_parths007").query(q)

response = s.execute()
print(response)
for hit in response:
    print(hit.meta.score, hit.test.available)
```

**EDIT** : Just read you need to do it on index time.

Elasticsearch deprecated index time boosting on 5.0
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/mapping-boost.html

You can use a [Boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) to achieve that on query time.

**Ingest Documents**

```
POST test_parths007/_doc
{
  "name": "doc1",
  "test": {
    "available": "ondemand"
  }
}

POST test_parths007/_doc
{
  "name": "doc1",
  "test": {
    "available": "higherscore"
  }
}

POST test_parths007/_doc
{
  "name": "doc2",
  "test": {
    "available": "higherscore"
  }
}
```

**Query (index time)**

```
POST test_parths007/_search
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "negative": {
        "term": {
          "test.available.keyword": "ondemand"
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_parths007",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "VMdY7XcB50NMsuQPelRx",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc2",
          "test" : {
            "available" : "higherscore"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_parths007",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Vcda7XcB50NMsuQPiVRB",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "test" : {
            "available" : "higherscore"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_parths007",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "U8dY7XcB50NMsuQPdlTo",
        "_score" : 0.5,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "test" : {
            "available" : "ondemand"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For more advanced manipulation you can check the [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it on index-time not query-time.

Comment: Any reason in particular to do it on index-time? Elasticsearch deprecated the index time boosting on 5.0 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/mapping-boost.html with more information maybe I can recommend you another approach.

Comment: Sorry for responding late but yes I know boosting is deprecated and I was looking for some other way which can help in increasing the score of other records than `ondemand` or decreasing it for `ondemand`.

Comment: I can do it on query time but I use `elasticsearch_dsl.query` `Q` to query the elasticsearch instance in python. If you are aware about any way to do it there, that would be great.

Comment: I have added some more info in the question, if that helps.

Comment: Now I understand. I could reproduce the boosting query in the python dsl format. I will edit my answer. Please let me know if it was useful

Comment: When I do the `GET` in kibana with the query you posted, it works but when I run in python client, I still see `ondemand` above in the UI

Comment: I ran the query I showed you in python and this was the output:

1.0 higherscore
1.0 higherscore
0.5 ondemand

Would be good if you can add your actual mappings and exact query to compare in my end and try to reproduce.

Comment: I added the exact mapping and the python code.

Comment: You should put your actual query inside the "positive" (replace the match_all) with it

Comment: @ParthS007 please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for your problem or let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Hey @llermaly, I asked another question related to ES here https://stackoverflow.com/q/66905358/7994074, Please have a look whenever you are available. Thanks