# Facets subtype and type results are not showing together in Elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have records mapped in Elasticsearch and the aggs looks like this:

```
aggregations : {

  r_type: {
    buckets: [
      0: {
       key: "test",
       doc_count: 57,
       r_subtype: {
         buckets: [
           0: {
            key: "y",
            doc_count: 5,
            label: "TEST",
            },
            ....
      ...
}
```

I am having problem showing a `r_subtype` and a `r_type` together in the search results.

When I select a `sub_type` from a `r_type` and another `r_type`, I only see the `sub_type` results.

This is the code in the path where I am filtering the results:

```
 def iter_aggs_options(self, options):
   """Iterate over aggregation options."""
   return options.get("aggs", {}).items()

def apply(self, identity, search, params):
    """Evaluate the query str on the search."""
    options = self.config.facets_options

    # Apply aggregations
    for name, agg in self.iter_aggs_options(options):
        # `aggs[]=` mutates `self.search`
        search.aggs[name] = agg if not callable(agg) else agg()

    # Apply post filters
    facets_args = params.pop('facets', {})
    post_filters = options.get("post_filters", {})

    for k in set(facets_args.keys()) & set(post_filters.keys()):
        filter_factory = post_filters[k]
        values = facets_args[k]
        values = values if isinstance(values, list) else [values]
        # Execute filter on search
        search = search.post_filter(filter_factory(values))
        # Set facet values on params (so they are available for links
        # generation)
        params[k] = values

    return search
```

Let me know what I might be missing or the question needs more info.